# Sourcetree GUI problems

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have a problem with the graphic environment in Sourcetree, as you can see on this image [Sourcetree error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUmx7.jpg)

You can see that the branches pannel appears with a black background and the popups menu appears with white font color.

I tried to desinstall and install more than 3 times, remove all the entries in my /appData/local/Altassian, installed latest version of Java (...just for try it) but nothing yet. I don't know what can be wrong.

This is the only application with this problem, the rest of my Windows 10's applications works fine. Work using git flow with this environment is a pain :(

Do you know what can be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Atlassian's support.

Comment: Posted here https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/37524942/sourcetree-gui-problems

Comment: Solved, that was a problem related with the window's theme. Seems that the theme selected "crashes" some window's colors.